# Is there a "non-linear limit" of the Dirac equation?

Tags: special-relativity, terminology, dirac-equation

I'm just going through old protocols of oral exams students wrote up. One student writes that he was supposed to derive the "non-linear limit" of the Dirac equation during the exam.

Is there a nonlinear limit of the Dirac equation, that I've never heard before, or is the student just referring to the well-known non-relativistic limit (Pauli equation)?

Comment: I would assume that the student means non-relativistic limit (characterized by the non-linear relation between energy an momentum).

Comment: @Vadim This is what he means with non-linear! makes sense. I'd be glad to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that the student means non-relativistic limit (characterized by the non-linear relation between energy an momentum).